# Regex Expression to match balanced double curly braces stored in an XML document

Tags: regex, xml, regex-lookarounds

I have a bit of an odd use case. I need to determine if a given string contains a "variable" within double curly braces; such as {{date}}. The below table represents the some of the use cases and the regex I am using, `(?<!\{)\{\{(?:([^{}]+))}}(?!})`, gives me the desired results.

| string/variable | result |
| --- | --- |
| text `{{date}}` text | true |
| text `{date}}` text | false |
| text `{{date}` text | false |
| text `{date{date}}` text | false |
| text `{{date}date}` text | false |
| text `{{{date}}}` text | true |
| text `{date{{date}}date}` text | true |
| text `{{date}}` some text `{date}}` text | true |

However, the problem I have is that I am required to have all JavaScript functions stored within an XML document.

Sort of like this:

```
<script_node>
   function foo(TextWithEmbeddedVars){
     var check = /(?<!\{)\{\{(?:([^{}]+))}}(?!})/.test(TextWithEmbeddedVars);
     return check;
   } 
</script_node>
```

Because the function is in an XML node the less than ("<") and greater than (">") symbols have to be written as `&lt;` or `&gt;` in order to not break the XML doc. But when you do this, `(?&lt;!\{)\{\{(?:([^{}]+))}}(?!})`, it breaks the regex pattern and it ceases to work.

Is there either a way to rewrite the regex to not require the less than symbol **or** a different way to write it and make it XML friendly?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Any software that tries to extract the regular expression from the XML document should be using an XML parser, and the XML parser will turn the `&lt;` back into `<`, so I can't see why you've got a problem. Unless you're trying to read XML without using an XML parser, in which case you're in deep trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing the function string in a [CDATA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createCDATASection) section should solve the problem as there's no need to escape reserved XML characters inside a CDATA section.
It is the recommended way of doing this.

```
<script_node><![CDATA[
   function foo(TextWithEmbeddedVars){
     var check = /(?<!\{)\{\{(?:([^{}]+))}}(?!})/.test(TextWithEmbeddedVars);
     return check;
   }]]>
</script_node>
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but there's a deeper problem. If the regex "doesn't work" as stated, then it's being read incorrectly from the XML document, and that means all kinds of other things could be wrong too.

Comment: The function it's first written to an XML and then read so this approach should not break the regex.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer because it is absolutely correct, CDATA should have resolved the issue. However, it turns out my issue was that my team was not informed that the servers where running Rhino JS which does Regex somewhat differently. Thank you for the response.